# How to get Angular JSON serializer to ignore null values?

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

I have an object that I send using HttpClient who may have some null properties. I wonder if there are any build-in solution(s) in Angular that ensure that null properties are not serialized.

Lets take this model for instance:

```
export class Dummy {
  public constructor(
    public readonly foo: string,
    public readonly bar: string
  ) { }
}
```

And this service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class DummyService {
  public constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public dummyMethod(dummyObject: Dummy): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.Post('https://api.dummy/v1/dummies', dummyObject)
  }
}
```

If `dummyObject === new Dummy("FooValue", null)` then I expect this JSON to be serialized: `{ "foo": "FooValue" }`

Comment: could you use `undefined` instead of `null`? `JSON.stringify`, which is user under the hood by the `HttpClient`, will ignore properties that are undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In JSON, values must be one of the following data types:
>
> ```
> a string
> a number
> an object (JSON object)
> an array
> a boolean
> null
> ```

So it can't ignore `null`. But we can't see `undefined` here, so you can use it instead of `null` and serialised object will omit it.